# Let $G$ be a group of order $27$ that acts on a set $X$ with $135$ elements. Prove for each $x_1,x_2\in X,{\rm Stab}_G(x_1)={\rm Stab}_G(x_2)$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-actions, p-groups

> Let $G$ be a group of order $27$ that acts on a set $X$ with $135$ elements. Prove that for each $x_1,x_2 \in X$ ${\rm Stab}_G(x_1) ={\rm Stab}_G(x_2)$.

I really can't think of anything useful here. I think it suffices to prove that every element $g \in G$ either fixes nothing or all the elements of $S$. I can't seem to go much further than that though. No need for the full solution, just a hint will do.

Thanks.

Comment: It's not remotely true.

Comment: @DavidA.Craven That's what I thought initially but this is a past exam problem. Perhaps it was a typo.

Comment: I cannot think of any way of changing words to make it work. If the action isn't transitive (where the statement obviously holds), just pick two subgroups of $G$, $H_1$ and $H_2$ and act on the cosets of $H_1$, union the action on the cosets of $H_2$. Then fill the rest with fixed points. In particular, if $G\neq 1$ and $|X|>|G|$ then it's never going to work. But $|G|=270$, $|X|=135$, is never going to work either. Basically, the only cases that will work are $|G|=p$, $|X|\leq p$ and generalizations, e.g., $|G|=6$, $|X|=2$.

Comment: @DavidA.Craven Thanks!

Comment: Why the downvotes? I've been occupied with this problem for a long time and couldn't make any progress so I posted it here. Turns out the problem is wrong!

Comment: Actually, now I look, the stabilizers of $x_1$ and $x_2$ are not usually equal even if they lie in the same orbit, as the stabilizers are conjugates. This question is completely wrong on all levels.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an 'answer' to this, let's answer the question 'if $|G|=n$ and $|X|=m$, when are we guaranteed that all stabilizers of elements of $X$ have the same order?' Equivalently, all orbits should have the same length, which makes it easier to understand.

Let $p$ be the smallest prime dividing $|G|$. If $|X|<p$ then all orbits must be of length $1$, and if $|X|=p$ then either all orbits have length $1$ or there is a single orbit of length $p$. So there is a positive answer if $|X|\leq p$.

If $|X|\geq p+1$ then we may take $G$ cyclic of order $n$, whence it has an action on $p$ points. Let $G$ act with a single orbit of length $p$, and $|X|-p$ orbits of length $1$.

If one requires two distinct orbits of length greater than $1$, then one may suitably modify this with $|G|=pqm$ where $q$ is the second smallest prime dividing $|G|$, or $p^2$ if $p^2\mid |G|$ and $p^2$ is smaller than the second smallest prime. Now the two smallest orbits have size $p$ and $q$, so the result holds if $|X|<p+q$.

(Of course, this is the statement for all groups of order $|G|$. If we restrict to specific groups then the answer will vary, and it depends on the minimal degree of a permutation representation.)

Comment: Thanks for the counterexample! +1